# Trying to exclude a substring within a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, skip

I have a list `phplist` containing the following strings (example below), there are many more, this is a snippet of the entire list

```
/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/config.php
/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/cache/classes/config.php
/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/theme/sky_high/config.php
/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/theme/brick/config.php
/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/theme/serenity/config.php
/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/theme/binarius/config.php
/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/theme/anomaly/config.php
/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/theme/standard/config.php
```

What I am trying to do is only keep the `subdir/config.php` file and exclude all other `config.php` files (eg cache/classes/config.php).

Full code is

```
for folder, subs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
                if filename.endswith('.php'):
                        phplist.append(abspath(join(folder, filename)))

for i in phplist:
           if i.endswith("/config.php"):
                    cmsconfig.append(i)
                    if i.endswith("/mdeploy.php"):
                            cmslist.append(cms1[18])
```

So the outcome will only add `/config.php` file path to the list `cmsconfig` but what is happening I am getting all the `config.php` files as in the top example

I have been using the code like `is not i.endswith("/theme/brick/config.php")` but I want a way to exclude the theme directory from the list.

The reason I am placing the output into a list is I use that output in another area of the code.

Comment: I'm smelling an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: (moodle) does the round brackets mean any subdirectory ?

Comment: does my new answer solve your task ?

Comment: no sorry, it does not I only want /config.php from the home directory(in this case moodle but the that directory could change) and no config files from the sub directories

Comment: you should update your example with one other path and your expected output

Comment: Just updated the question with more info and the outcome I am trying to achieve @fuubah

Comment: I found a work around to get the outcome I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Change your if-condition to `if i.endswith("moodle/config.php")`.

If you want to change the folder that you want to this with:

```
path_ending = '%s/config.php' % folder_name
```

Now change the if-condition to `if i.endswith(path_ending)`

This will show paths that end with `config.php` within the folder tbat you passed.

Comment: would like moodle to be any dir ie public_html. etc

Comment: You can replace the folder name (in this case with moodle) with something else.

Comment: Yes i understand that, Ill show you what I am trying to do in full.

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
                if filename.endswith('.php'):
                        phplist.append(abspath(join(folder, filename)))

for i in phplist:
         if i.endswith("/config.php") is not i.endswith("/base/config.php"):
                        cmsconfig.append(i)
                        if i.endswith("/mdeploy.php"):
                                cmslist.append(cmsdirectory[18])

Comment: @Robbie you should put the code in the question. It clarifies the context of the question much more.

Comment: Totally agree, this was my first question here. been coding python for 4 weeks and have a nice little script that counts files and filetype but stuck at defining what cms's are running and their configuration file locations.. thanks for your help tho @fixxxer

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. may change the naming of variables it is not pep8 style.

First i sort all entries that the shortest comes first, then i remember which parts are already checked.

```
url1 = '/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/theme/binarius/config.php'
url2 = '/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/config.php'
url3 = '/home/comradec/public_html/othername/theme/binarius/config.php'
url4 = '/home/comradec/public_html/othername/config.php'

urls = []
urls.append(url1)
urls.append(url2)
urls.append(url3)
urls.append(url4)

moodleUrls = []
checkedDirs = []

#sort
for i in sorted(urls):
    if str(i).endswith('config.php'):

        alreadyChecked = False
        for checkedDir in checkedDirs:
            if str(i).startswith(checkedDir):
               alreadyChecked = True
               break

        if not alreadyChecked:
            moodleUrls.append(i)
            checkedDirs.append(str(i).replace('/config.php',''))

print(checkedDirs)
print(moodleUrls)
```

Output:

```
['/home/comradec/public_html/moodle', '/home/comradec/public_html/othername']
['/home/comradec/public_html/moodle/config.php', '/home/comradec/public_html/othername/config.php']
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved my question. Provides the output I am looking for.

```
path = "/home/comradec"
phplist = []
cmsconfig = []
config = "config.php"

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
                if filename.endswith('.php'):
                        phplist.append(abspath(join(folder, filename)))
for i in phplist:
          if i.endswith("/mdeploy.php"):
                        newurl = i
                        newurl = newurl[:-11]
                        newurl = newurl + config
                        for i in phplist:
                                if i.endswith("/config.php"):
                                        confirmurl = i
                                        if confirmurl == newurl:
                                                cmsconfig.append(newurl)
print('\n'.join(cmsconfig))
```